# Javascript UI isn't working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

This problem is caused by my acknowledge of English and jQuery or maybe something else.
I was using tutorial for jQuery - http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/ .

In my application.erb.html:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "rails.validations", "rails.validations.custom" %>
<%=  javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"%>
<%=javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"%>
```

I think I didn't included some library because my page in view.

But my page looks like:

```
    0 Comments
    Say something!
```

**EDITED**

My generator didn't created js files,so I created file rails.validations.custom.js and added code from GitHub:

```
   ClientSideValidations.validators.local['email'] = function(element, options) {
    // Your validator code goes in here
      if (!/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.test(element.val())) {
    // When the value fails to pass validation you need to return the error message.
    // It can be derived from validator.message
    return options.message;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for messages about missing scripts?

Comment: Do you mean to look in logs ?

Comment: In Chrome e.g. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console Tools > Developer Tools from the Chrome 'spanner' menu.

Comment: Yup. I don't use FireBug anymore so can't tell you specifically where to look, but basically you're looking for 404 errors.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/defaults.js

Comment: also I have troubles with client side validation

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/rails.validations.custom.js

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined rails.validations.js:126

Comment: There you go - now you just need to figure out why those files are missing, or why the paths to those files are not pointing where you expect. I'm not a rails guy so I can't help with debugging your rails code.

Comment: @DenMed your scripts are not loading properly. Check the paths of the .js file and include them on page properly.

Comment: It's easy to say, but hard to do for that newby like me.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, place the two missing JS files in the /assets directory at your application's root level.

Comment: I will edit problem to tell you what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments thread for the question is getting long, so I'm going to create an answer.

We have established by looking at the firebug console that two of your JavaScript files are not where your application expects them to be:

```
/assets/defaults.js
/assets/rails.validations.custom.js
```

What you need to do is either move those two files to the `/assets` directory, or modify the file path to point to the location where those two files actually reside.

I'm not a rails guy, but here is my guess about how you might do that:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "/js/rails.validations", "/js/rails.validations.custom" %>
```

I *think* this would look for the files in `/assets/js` directory, but obviously you would need to modify the path to point at the actual location of you files. I'm sure a rails developer will chime in and tell me if I've got the wrong end of the stick!

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/rails.validations.custom.js 404 (Not Found)when Edited

Comment: So what does that tell you? Your application expects a file at /js/rails.validations.custom.js and it's not there. Where did you put it? Modify your path accordingly.

Comment: I put them into assets/javascripts folder

Comment: I think this errors caused by my acknowled basics of rails. I will read about that helpers. Thank you very much for helping me. I wish you a lot of happiness)

Comment: Based on what you've told me, I think you need to change your helper tag to:

<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "/assets/javascripts/rails.validations", "/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.custom" %>

I would suggest you read the documentation for javascript_include_tag, and I think you probably need to get your head around the concept of file paths. Good luck!

Comment: When I put those files into javascript folder they SHOULD BE included by default. I don't understand it...

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Basically the process of debugging a broken asset URL is: 1) Look at the 404 error message, which tells you where the web page expects to find your asset. 2) Compare this path to the *actual* location of the file. 3) Change the file path in the app to the actual file location. Sorry that's all I have time for tonight! Good luck.